# Cannot implement linerGradient() in TextView inside onCreate() method

Tags: android, textview, oncreate, linear-gradients

I want to implement `linearGradient()` in my textView. I want it in a way so that when the activity loads up, the `linearGradient()` gets applied on my textview. I was able to do it in a button click listener, but the linear gradient does not work whenever I implement it in the `onCreate()` method. Below is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:text="Apply Gradient Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java** file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView tv;
    private Button btn;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private Shader shader;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv.setText(" Instagram  ");
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/billabong.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(face);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        mWidth=tv.getWidth();
        mHeight=tv.getHeight();
        Point size = new Point(mWidth,mHeight);
        GradientManager gm= new GradientManager(getApplicationContext(),size);
        shader=gm.getRandomLinearGradient();
        tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
        tv.getPaint().setShader(shader);
    }
}
```

**GradientManager.java** file:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Shader;


public class GradientManager {
    private Point mSize;

    public GradientManager(Context context, Point size){
        this.mSize = size;
    }

    protected LinearGradient getRandomLinearGradient(){

        LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, mSize.x, mSize.y,
                new int[] {Color.parseColor("#6656C8"), Color.parseColor("#8E33A9"),Color.parseColor("#BB328C"), Color.parseColor("#ED4B3E"),
                        Color.parseColor("#FA8031"), Color.parseColor("#FEC65C"), Color.parseColor("#FFD374") },null,
                Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
        );
        return gradient;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot when activity starts:**
[image: Image 1]

**Screenshot when I press the button:**
[image: Image 2]

What I want to implement is given below (I removed the button):

**MainActivity.java** file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private Shader shader;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(" Instagram  ");
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/billabong.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(face);
        mWidth=tv.getWidth();
        mHeight=tv.getHeight();
        Point size = new Point(mWidth,mHeight);
        GradientManager gm= new GradientManager(getApplicationContext(),size);
        shader=gm.getRandomLinearGradient();
        tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
        tv.getPaint().setShader(shader);       
    }   
}
```

The contents of **GradientManager.java** is unchanged, Only the button is removed from my layout. The above code does not show any gradient color, instead It displays the whole textView with the first color of the linear gradient color parameter [Color.parseColor("#6656C8")]. 
**This is my screenshot:** [image: Image 3]

Can someone please help me with the code? What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using tv.getWidth and getHeight during onCreate. At that time TextView is not measured yet therefore those values are not valid. İf you have to get width and height for gradient you should apply your gradient after measure step is done(i.e. using ongloballayoutlistener).

Comment: Actually I needed a way to aply linear gradient like this in onCreate(). I searched everywhere, but I cudn't find one. So I had to put hardcoded values instead of tv.width and tv.height. Can you please give me a solution to implement the same? So that in I get the length and breadth of any textview text that's been given in the set Text(). This code does not work even if I put some values in the layout xml file.